# R: How to create multiple maps (rworldmap) with different classification borders?

Tags: r

Based on my former [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945984/r-how-to-create-multiple-maps-rworldmap-using-apply) answered by @Andy, I wanted to have different classification intervals per map using Jenks natural breaks. For this I use the library `classInt`, which works fine for single plots. However, I don't know how to implement this different classifications per column (or map) into the `lapply` solution of @Andy. Which is probably pretty easy. So using the sample data of my previous question I would create the classification intervals like this (based on the `spdf` object):

```
library(classInt)
# create classification intervalls for single columsn
classInt_Bv <- classIntervals( spdf$BLUE.veggies, n=3, style="jenks")
Bv = classInt_Bv$brks
classInt_Bf <- classIntervals( spdf$BLUE.fruits, n=3, style="jenks")
Bf = classInt_Bf$brks
classInt_Bn <- classIntervals( spdf$BLUE.nuts, n=3, style="jenks")
Bn = classInt_Bn$brks
classInt_Gv <- classIntervals( spdf$GREEN.veggies, n=3, style="jenks")
Gv = classInt_Gv$brks
classInt_Gf <- classIntervals( spdf$GREEN.fruits, n=3, style="jenks")
Gf = classInt_Gf$brks
classInt_Gn <- classIntervals( spdf$GREEN.nuts, n=3, style="jenks")
Gn = classInt_Gn$brks
# merge all cols again together
catMethod = data.frame(Bv,Bf,Bn,Gv,Gf,Gn)
```

Here, maybe my first question is there a easier/faster way to do this? As I use in 2nd df more than 50 cols.

My 2nd (and main) question is: How to implement these classification intervals into @Andy's lapply function, so that every map uses the wright classification intervals? Thanks

Comment: You can try `lapply(spdf, function(x) classIntervals(spdf(x, n=3, style='jenks')$brks)`

Comment: @akrun. I get the error `Error in as.list.default(X) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector`. Any ideas?

Comment: There was a typo, `i1 <- grep('^(BLUE|GREEN)', names(spdf)); lapply(spdf[i1], function(x) classIntervals(x, n=3, style='jenks')$brks)` (this works on the example posted on the link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example provided in the link

```
spdf <- df
```

As there are non-numeric columns, we can subset the dataset for those columns with names that have either 'BLUE' or 'GREEN' with `grep` ('i1'), then we loop over those columns,apply the `classIntervals` function and get the 'brks' in a `list`.

```
i1 <- grep('^(BLUE|GREEN)', names(spdf))
lst <- lapply(spdf[i1], function(x) classIntervals(x, n=3,
                 style='jenks')$brks)
names(lst) <- sub('^(.)[^.]+.(.).*', '\\1\\2', names(lst))
res <- data.frame(lst)
res 
#        Bf       Bn     Bv       Gf      Gn     Gv
#1        0        0      0        0       0      0
#2  3745797   171984  34910  3389314  464688  15508
#3 12803543   533665  92690  8942278 1640804 149581
#4 19947613 21563867 188940 15773576 6399474 174504
```

Comment: Your answer works fine for the first part. Do you have an idea how to deal with the 2nd (main) question? And just an info: spdf is needed for the plotting, therefore I changed all the spdf in your code for df.